# How to test for label of a field from translate service using jasmine

Tags: jasmine, ngx-translate

I am new to unit testing of angular code using jasmine. I am trying to test the label of a field , which is got from translate service in HTML file.
I have used the below code, but i am getting error "Failed: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null"

```
it('label should be Enter your mobile number', async(() => {
     const de = fixture.debugElement;
     expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[id=textFormat] label').textContent).toEqual('ENTER_YOUR_MOBILE_NUMBER'); 
     translate.setTranslation('en', { ENTER_YOUR_MOBILE_NUMBER : 'Enter your mobile number' });
    translate.use('en');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('[id=textFormat] label').textContent).toEqual('Enter your mobile number'); 
       }));


HTML :

<div class="form-group" id="email">
        <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-form-label col-form-label-lg" id="textFormat">
            {{ 'ENTER_YOUR_MOBILE_NUMBER' | translate }}&nbsp;<span class="labelHint" id="numbFormat">(05XXXXXXXX)</span>
        </label>
       
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your CSS selector is not accurate, try this:

```
it('label should be Enter your mobile number', async(() => {
     const de = fixture.debugElement;
     expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('label#textFormat').textContent).toEqual('ENTER_YOUR_MOBILE_NUMBER'); 
     translate.setTranslation('en', { ENTER_YOUR_MOBILE_NUMBER : 'Enter your mobile number' });
    translate.use('en');
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('label#textForma').textContent).toEqual('Enter your mobile number'); 
       }));
```

Change what goes in the `querySelector`.